# Implement Live Broadcast by Agora.io

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am trying to implement Live Broadcast by Agora.io in React Native mobile application. I have previously implemented video call successfully. I have gone through documentation, compare and contrast video call to live broadcast ( both web sdk). I could only find a difference in *mode* of the client which corresponds to *channelProfile* in react-native sdk. In documentation it says there are three different modes: Communication, Live Broadcast and Gaming. When I implemented video call I assigned 1 for the value of channelProfile, it worked fine, quality was good enough. However, when I assign 2 for channelProfile to indicate it is a Live Broadcast, the quality goes heavily down. Do I make anything wrong while implementation of Live Broadcast? How can I improve the quality of Live Broadcast?
For consideration, I put my code below:

```
const config = {
        appid: 'MY APP ID',
        channelProfile: this.props.navigation.getParam('channelProfile', 2),
        clientRole: this.props.navigation.getParam('clientRole', 1),
        videoEncoderConfig: {
            width: 360,
            height: 480,
            bitrate: 1,
            frameRate: FPS30,
            orientationMode: Adaptative,
        },
        audioProfile: AudioProfileDefault,
        audioScenario: AudioScenarioDefault
    }
    RtcEngine.on('userJoined', (data) => {
        console.warn("user joined", data);
        const { peerIds } = this.state;
        if (peerIds.indexOf(data.uid) === -1) {
            this.setState({
                peerIds: [...this.state.peerIds, data.uid]
            })
        }
    })
    RtcEngine.on('error', (error) => {
        console.warn("error", error);
    })
    RtcEngine.init(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Agora's SDK there used to be three channel-modes, but recently the gaming SDK has been combined with the native SDKs so there are only two channel-modes, `communication` and `broadcast`.

Each mode optimizes for different qualities within the channel and within the streams. For broadcasting the documentation mentions that when using default bitrate that `broadcast` mode uses twice the bitrate of `communication`.

If you are having quality issues you should consider changing your bitrate, currently your code is setting the bitrate to `1` which is very low. Agora provides a list of suggested resolution profiles, fps, and bit rates.

Agora Video Bitrate documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/oc/Classes/AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration.html#//api/name/bitrate

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I found out that 0 value of channelProfile is used for video chat and 1 is used for broadcast. Value of 2 doesn't exist and therefore, the quality was bad.